# Unable to programmatically toggle (close only) Highchart's default Context Menu using jQuery.toggle()

Tags: jquery, highcharts, toggle, contextmenu

I am not an expert at all but I am genuinely losing my mind on this.

The comments included in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DixiPoowa/c9wf6ft6/7/) should be clear enough but I'll explain everything here too.

I want to be able to close HC's default Context Menu by clicking on the default hamburger button when the menu is already visible (because reasons...).

So I noticed a few things:

- By default, HC positions the menu with padding, therefore "blocking" the background with the invisible div hitbox. I already took care of that

  ```
  padding: 0 48px !important; /* just for the demo, i'm leaving the sides on */
  margin: 48px 0 !important;
  ```
- After programmatically generating the context menu, during the first click on export button, it switches state and now his click event displays the context menu (but that's all I think). That's why I "unbind" its click event, and add mine.

`contextMenuButton.one("click touchstart", function(e){
    /* Remove HC's events because I want a special behavior and don't know how to do it any other way, maybe I can extend or something ? */
    $(contextMenuButton).prop('onclick',null).off('click');
    /* My behaviour */
    contextMenuButton.on("click touchstart", function(n){
        toastr.info("tmpButtonContextMenu " + n.type + " custom");
        tmp = contextMenuButton.parent().next(".highcharts-contextmenu").first();
        tmp.toggle();
    });
});`

At this point I was seriously expecting it to work. I even tried doing it myself

`tmp.css("display", tmp.css("display") == "none" ? "block" : "none";`

Or JS

`tmp[0].style.display = tmp[0].style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";`

But it still doesn't change anything.

After a while I noticed a prop `hidden=true`so I  tried playing with it a little but nothing changed...

I know I should just create my own menu and it would be much easier (and I'll be doing that anyway) but at this point I just want to know WHY it's acting the way it is.

**tl;dr**:

I'm switching HC's default context-menu's padding for a margin so I can click elements behind it and I want to be able to close said menu by clicking the export button (hamburger) again.

**PS**:

I'm using a library called ToastrJS for my mobile debugging (since I don't have a console there) and it proves that, indeed, my "custom" click is being called.

**Edit:**

Since I want to also keep the capability of closing the context menu by clicking anywhere else, I slightly modified the prototype like so:

```
addEvent(doc, 'mouseup', function (e) {  
    if($(e.target.parentElement).hasClass("highcharts-contextmenu-toggler"))  
        css(menu, { display: 'none' });  
    else   
        hide();  
})
```

and, at the end :

```
if(chart.openMenu){
    chart.openMenu = false;
} else {
    css(menu, menuStyle);
    chart.openMenu = true;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I should just create my own menu and it would be much easier
>   (and I'll be doing that anyway) but at this point I just want to know
>   WHY it's acting the way it is.

It happens because Highcharts launches its own logic for hiding context menu anyway:

```
                        if (!chart.pointer.inClass(e.target, className)) {
                            hide();
                        }
```

So if you use `toggle()` you actually show the menu (it's already hidden in that moment).

---

**Workaround**:

I've overwritten `Chart.prototype.contextMenu` function and commented out the above piece of code.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lr74sou8/

Comment: I knew Highcharts was doing something on its own and that's why I wanted to unbind everything but I would've never suspected that kind of behaviour (I'm still a newbie and I learn everyday, my biggest problem now is my code organisation ^^ I've read few articles about "namespaces" and I'll probably do that in later projects but for now, this one is doomed to stay dirty I guess). I even tried to read the non-minified code ahah.

And for some reason I didn't get a SO notification about your answer. Thank god I check myself, you just saved me ! Thank you very much

Comment: Arf... My changes create an error when using `chart.destroy()` (half way through the process because the export and/or custom buttons are all destroyed, but not the chart itself). I'll stick to your code for now.

Comment: OK! Last update (I hope): The error I was having when deleting a graph was something like "function is undefined". And the reason was simple, I declared my behaviour with jQuery, and, when deleting a graph, HC deletes every created events (I suppose). So it must've been searching for the JS mouseup event, and wasn't able to find it. by switching from `$(document).on("mouseup", function(e){` to `addEvent(doc, 'mouseup', function (e) {` the problem was solved. (At least for now hehe)